# Implementing two contact forms with validation controls in a single page in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm using two contact forms in the same aspx page, one has 4 textbox controls (name- email- subject- body) and send button control.
The second form has 2 textbox controls and send button, all (except the second textbox of the second form) has validation controls (requiredFieldValidator).

This is the code inside the first button click event:

```
  protected void ButtonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsValid)
        {
            LabelIRespond.Visible = true;
            .....
        }
    }
```

there is no code in the second button click event. 
the problem is, when the first form validated successful and the second form not validated, the code inside click event not executed. and the error message of the second form appears. They act like they are one form!

The markup for both forms:

```
<section id="sendSection">   
    <div id="contactMe">
        <h1>Contact me</h1>
    </div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

    <h4>Send me a message:</h4>
    <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style8">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail" placeholder="Your Email address" runat="server" BackColor="#D4D8DF"  Font-Names="Century Gothic" CssClass="txtbxs" Height="25px" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Email address">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style8">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" placeholder="Your name" runat="server" BackColor="#D4D8DF" Font-Names="Century Gothic" CssClass="txtbxs" Height="25px" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxName" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style5">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSubject" placeholder="Subject" runat="server" BackColor="#D4D8DF" Font-Names="Century Gothic" CssClass="txtbxs" Height="25px" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorSubject" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxSubject" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxBody" placeholder="What do you want to tell me?"  runat="server" BackColor="#D4D8DF" TextMode="MultiLine" Font-Names="Century Gothic" CssClass="txtbxs" Height="180px" Width="370px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorBody" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxBody" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Type your message">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style8">
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonSend" runat="server" Text="Send" CssClass="btnSend" Width="80px" OnClick="ButtonSend_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Font-Names="Century Gothic" />
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style8">
                <asp:Label ID="LabelIRespond" runat="server" Text="Thanks, your message has been sent. I'll respond ASAP." Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
                        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="wait">
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

</section>                 
<div class="split"></div>

<section id="viewCVSection">
    <div id="check">
        <h1>Check out my CV</h1>
    </div>



    <div class="cvForm">
<table class="auto-style1">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail2" placeholder="Company Email address" CssClass="txtbxs" runat="server" BackColor="#D4D8DF" Height="25px" Width="250px" Font-Names="Century Gothic"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail2" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail2" CssClass="ErrorMessage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxCompany" placeholder="Company name" CssClass="txtbxs" runat="server" BackColor="#D4D8DF" Height="25px" Width="250px" Font-Names="Century Gothic"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="sendCV" runat="server" Text="Request CV" Font-Names="Century Gothic" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: You need to use ValidationGroup as mentioned in my answer. Set ValidationGroup for first contact form button and its validators to `FirstGroup` and then set the same property for second contact form button and validators to `SecondGroup`. It will work then.

Comment: Also `ButtonSend1` is in which contact form?

Comment: first form. I've edited my question so it contain the markup for both forms now

Comment: Can you follow what I said in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook up validation controls with the correct button. Right now,  button click in first form is causing validation in first contact form as well as second contact form, which is causing `Page.IsValid` to be false since second form fields are empty and therefore invalid.

So set the validation group of first contact form different from the second contact form as in code below. Then set the `ValidationGroup` on corresponding validation controls with the same value.

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSend" runat="server" Text="Send" CssClass="btnSend"
 Width="80px" OnClick="ButtonSend_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" 
   Font-Names="Century Gothic" ValidationGroup="FirstGroup"/>



<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="sendCV" runat="server" 
 Text="Request CV" Font-Names="Century Gothic" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
  ValidationGroup="SecondGroup"/>
```

**NOTE**: Make sure that all validation controls have their `ValidationGroup` also set to appropriate value after you make above code change.

Comment: This validationGroup property must set to validation controls along with its corresponding buttons?  should I set the property for the textbox controls?

Comment: Not for text boxes. Just set the `ValidationGroup` on all validator controls and buttons.